# how to get gmail contacts with photo in php

Tags: php, xml, authentication, gmail

HI i have a code to grab gmail contacts with php. First i get session token and later go to that url:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$maxresults.'&oauth_token='. $_SESSION['token']

so i have a contacts now but cant grab images from contacts. I have a link to contact image:

```
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxx%40gmail.com/2e" />
```

but when i enter on that url google tells me somethings wrong and no more informations. Have you any solution or idea how can i grab images from gmail contacts list ?

Regards

Comment: The URL has to have oauth_token, I think, since it's accessible only if signed in

Comment: And which URL do you mean? It's not clear from your question. Also by Google tells you something is wrong, do you mean Google the Webrowser or Google the site administrator. Also "something is wrong" is not an adequate technical error description.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (javascript)

```
function fetchGooglePhotosUrl(defaultEmail, contactId, token) {
    return "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/" + encodeURIComponent(defaultEmail) + "/" + contactId + "?access_token=" + token;
}
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo)